# databinding error in telerik social share

Tags: c#, telerik

the code

```
    <telerik:RadSocialShare ID="RadSocialShare1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" >
    <MainButtons>
    <telerik:RadFacebookButton ButtonType="FacebookLike" UrlToShare='<%# Eval("FACEBOOK_LINK", "{0}")%>' Width="50" />
    </MainButtons>
    </telerik:RadSocialShare>
```

error message:

```
Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. Telerik.Web.UI.RadFacebookButton does not have a DataBinding event.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because you have used Eval in its property. This is not the Data/List control like Grid, ListView, TreeView, DropDownList...etc.

Please remove Eval from the below code snippet.

```
UrlToShare='<%# Eval("FACEBOOK_LINK", "{0}")%>'
```

If you used this control in inside any Data/List control then use those control's databinding event to get this control and assign value in it.